# How to properly create a Parrot OS 4.10 (amd64) USB flash drive with persistence from Windows 7?

Tags: linux, usb, persistence, parrot-os

I am trying to add a persistence live bootable Parrot OS 4.10 amd64 on an 8GB USB (SanDisk Cruzer Blade USB 2.0) from Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit. No matter whatever method I’ve tried, I just get stuck with a live USB without persistence.

And here’s what I had tried:

- First, I tried this using [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). It did create a live USB but no persistence.
- Tried with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) with 3GB as persistence, but still didn't work.

Tried this:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/my_usb
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/my_usb
echo "/ union" > /mnt/my_usb/persistence.conf
umount /dev/sdb2
```

Formatted the new partition as ext4 and then tried the above method.

I am pretty sure that it’s not the problem with ISO as I installed it from the [official Parrot OS](https://www.parrotsec.org/) page and also I’ve installed in a VM and it works pretty good.

I am also sure that it’s not a problem with the USB cause I’ve tried all these with another USB too.

What can I do to get this working?